# How to position TextFormField to bottom of screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have been trying to position my TextFormField button to the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is not in view then it moves up when the keyboard is in view.i have tried using a list view and it did not workout, i am a newbie to flutter and i don't know much about it.  heres is my code and screenshot thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu7Sd.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:untitled/ui/view/threadModel/thread_viewmodel.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:untitled/ui/view/comment_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ThreadView extends StatelessWidget {
// const ThreadView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ViewModelBuilder<ThreadViewModel>.reactive(
  builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: HexColor('00b87c'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      //foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      toolbarHeight: 54,
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
        color: HexColor('#333333'),
        size: 16,
      ),
      titleSpacing: 0,

      title: Text(
        model.threads,
        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            //letterSpacing: 0.5,
            color: HexColor('#201e1f'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 212),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 21, 16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 16),
                        Text(
                          'Message in',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            color: HexColor('#727272'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 4,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          size: 12,
                          color: HexColor('#1A61DB'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 4,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'team-socrates',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            color: HexColor('#1A61DB'),
                            fontSize: 12,
                            //textBaseline: ,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(4),
                            ),
                          ),
                          width: 42,
                          height: 42,
                          child: FittedBox(
                            child: Image.asset('images/Rectangle 172.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'princessliz',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                  height: 14,
                                  width: 14,
                                  child:
                                      Image.asset('images/Group 1280.png'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '30 Aug at 20:31',
                              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.bookmark_border_outlined,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Aristotle - @caculuz.,\n"
                      "Aquinas - @caculuz.,\n"
                      "Socrates - @Feranmi..",
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        //     letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        height: 1.3,
                        color: HexColor('#424141'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: HexColor('#93B0E1'),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(5),
                        ),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: HexColor('#1a61db'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: 45,
                      height: 25,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            "images/po.png",
                            width: 16,
                            height: 16,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '3',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            //height: 20,
            //thickness: 0.5,
            //endIndent: 0,
            color: HexColor('#7b8794'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 12, 20, 13),
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "1 reply",
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      // letterSpacing: ,
                      color: HexColor('#424141'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.forward_outlined,
                        size: 24,
                        color: HexColor('#424141'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 33.92,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.more_vert_rounded,
                        color: HexColor('#424141'),
                        size: 24,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            //height: 20,
            //thickness: 0.5,
            //endIndent: 0,
            color: HexColor('#7b8794'),
          ),
          Comment(),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 8, 0),
                      hintText: "Add a reply",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  viewModelBuilder: () => ThreadViewModel(),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextFormField to bottom of screen'),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black12,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('This is your home page'), // body: SingleChildScrollView(...)
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding:
                  new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 8.0),
              hintText: 'Enter text',
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Screenshots:**

[image] [image]